# How to overwrite a block data that already exists in mifare 1K tag. Authentication fails when trying to override the data ina specific block

Tags: nfc, rfid, mifare

I write a data say 'qwerty' in a block 05 (keyA). Try reading it. its successful. trying to update/rewrite the same block with another data say 'asdfg'. but i could'nt authenticate the block. getting error message.

Am i missing any settings or any suggestions on this issue

Comment: You must include more details; code etc, so that people have a better idea of what you're doing, how you're (trying to) doing it, and what the problem could be. If you don't update your question to include sufficient detail, people will likely vote to close your question (or just ignore it altogether).

Comment: Isn't it so that you need to use KEY_B for writing?

Answer (score 1):

Did you also write the access bits? In normal condition, it won't be any problem for authentication if you do not change access bits.

Comment: In other words, check your access bits before attempting write operations.